# Does Al-Sihir (magic) still exist?

Tags: quran, sihr

I know that magic has been mentioned in the Quran but somehow these verses are referring to the magic done in order to move from one place to another in no time or making people believe false things.

However; I want to know if another types of magic exists. Specifically, the one that plays with human emotions and make someone hate his wife or make someone love a girl. Does this type of magic exist?

Comment: I would think so.  There are those who cause enmity between two or more people.  This is called slandering : http://sunnah.com/urn/368400

Comment: @AlUmmat: That doesn't count as magic.

Comment: Maybe this could help http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7651/does-magic-exist-in-reality?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Yes this form of Magic exist.

Quran says:

> وَاتَّبَعُوا مَا تَتْلُو الشَّيَاطِينُ عَلَى مُلْكِ سُلَيْمَانَ وَمَا
>   كَفَرَ‌ سُلَيْمَانُ وَلَـكِنَّ الشَّيَاطِينَ كَفَرُ‌وا يُعَلِّمُونَ
>   النَّاسَ السِّحْرَ‌ وَمَا أُنزِلَ عَلَى الْمَلَكَيْنِ بِبَابِلَ
>   هَارُ‌وتَ وَمَارُ‌وتَ وَمَا يُعَلِّمَانِ مِنْ أَحَدٍ حَتَّى يَقُولَا
>   إِنَّمَا نَحْنُ فِتْنَةٌ فَلَا تَكْفُرْ‌ فَيَتَعَلَّمُونَ مِنْهُمَا
>   مَا يُفَرِّ‌قُونَ بِهِ بَيْنَ الْمَرْ‌ءِ وَزَوْجِهِ وَمَا هُم
>   بِضَارِّ‌ينَ بِهِ مِنْ أَحَدٍ إِلَّا بِإِذْنِ اللَّـهِ
>   وَيَتَعَلَّمُونَ مَا يَضُرُّ‌هُمْ وَلَا يَنفَعُهُمْ وَلَقَدْ عَلِمُوا
>   لَمَنِ اشْتَرَ‌اهُ مَا لَهُ فِي الْآخِرَ‌ةِ مِنْ خَلَاقٍ وَلَبِئْسَ
>   مَا شَرَ‌وْا بِهِ أَنفُسَهُمْ لَوْ كَانُوا يَعْلَمُونَ
>
> And they followed [instead] what the devils had recited during the
>   reign of Solomon. It was not Solomon who disbelieved, but the devils
>   disbelieved, teaching people magic and that which was revealed to the
>   two angels at Babylon, Harut and Marut. But the two angels do not
>   teach anyone unless they say, "We are a trial, so do not disbelieve
>   [by practicing magic]." And [yet] they learn from them that by which
>   they cause separation between a man and his wife. But they do not harm
>   anyone through it except by permission of Allah. And the people learn
>   what harms them and does not benefit them. But the Children of Israel
>   certainly knew that whoever purchased the magic would not have in the
>   Hereafter any share. And wretched is that for which they sold
>   themselves, if they only knew. http://tanzil.net/#2:102

This knowledge that was taught by these two angels to Jews has passed during history and today it is called Kabbalah. This knowledge is taught to cancel the magic of evil magicians. And the two angels taken promise to this knowledge not be used for evil purposes. For canceling an evil effect, believer scholars should have its knowledge. But still Jews use this knowledge for evil purposes. This magic is possible by selling the soul to Satan. But the may think they have sold their soul to God.

---

**Reference:**

[Jews and Kabbalah](http://www.alvadossadegh.com/fa/article/48-secret-organization/21936-1391-05-03-21-56-54.html)

Comment: Is there any English version of the article present that you have sited in the answer?

Comment: @HashimR I do not know. sorry. but maybe google translate be useful.

Comment: -1 You are blaming the Jews, yet the Verse says nothing about Jews.

Comment: @AmericanMuslim this verse has interpretation. Quran blames Jews. not me. http://tanzil.net/#5:82

Comment: I do not see that verse in your answer.

Comment: @AmericanMuslim that verse is for your comment. my answer is based on  Tafseer of verse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and there are magicians who listen to the Shaitan and tell them about the future the meteor could reach the Shaitan before he tells him or not and he could tell him but he lies in his talking If you can speak Arabic I would send you a program on television talking about the magic and these things.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think such magic still exists. I believe that the existing of Miracles/Magic ended when the last Prophet (PBUH) passed away.

Unlike many I can back that up with some sort of proof. Some scholars associate the Ayah for Magic (2:102) with the Jews as explained [here](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=645&idto=668&bk_no=48&ID=130). Now tell me, if Jews really had the power to make people sick, etc. Through magic wouldn't they have used it on their enemies and rules the world?

The same exists for those who claim this is something that exists. Imagine I start a business where I can make a supermodel fall in love with you, many people would pay millions of dollars to do so, it would be a very large scale operation (like drugs, prostitution, every other bad thing is). The same goes for marrying a rich person, etc.

Possession is something also closely associate with Magic (where someone would make a spell to have a person possessed by the devil). That I don't believe in entirely and think it just fake.

I think that this tradition of magic/possession/miracles, was carried over from the old ages, many years ago when things like this would be told and people would believe in them because of the simplistical minds. Notice that the Muslims during their golden age never reported such theories and only once we dwindled down our knowledge that Muslims started believing in such nonsense.