# Does indirect belief in magic make me a disbeliever?

Tags: kufr, sihr, doubts, waswasa

I have constant feelings of doubt in [magic](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7651/does-magic-exist-in-reality). I constantly tell myself that I do believe in it, however I feel that I don't and only think that I do  due to fear of Allah. A few days ago I had this thought "If I really do believe can I swear by Allah that it is true?" And I couldn't bring myself to do so. Am I a disbeliever and if I am, how do I start believing?

Comment: WHat do you mean by believing in magic? Magic IS a reality and there is no doubt in it. It is a big haraam though. Your question needs some explanation

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Quran is a book of knowledge. There is no doubt in it. That is a firm belief of a true Muslim.

How does one acquire knowledge? Through reasoning. Using God given mental faculties.

Now let's apply reasoning to the world and universe around us. Cause and effect is everywhere. Without a physical cause affecting someone or something is not how nature and physical laws (all made by God - a firm belief of Muslims) work. If it rains, all get wet if u stand in rain - it's not biased towards this group or that group. If you put your hand in fire it will burn. That is a fundamental law of nature that God has made for us.

You may recite 'Ya Razzaq' Dhikr a million times, it doesn't feed your tummy unless you make some efforts to earn your Rizq and pray to Allah SWT that your efforts bear fruit - Example of this is narrated in the Quranic story about Abraham AS and his son Ismail AS who built the Kaaba and prayed to Allah to accept their efforts.

So, in this world where even a leaf doesn't magically move with a cause, it's not rational to think that by some mumbo jumbo someone gains significant unfair advantage over other human beings. This belief if upheld, defeats the whole purpose of creation of human beings which is to test them in this world. This world is a level playing field for all human beings of sane mind when it comes to their evaluation in the Hereafter. Otherwise we will have an argument against God in the Hereafter that Nauzubillah His judgement is unfair because during the test, he didn't keep the playing field equal for all participants.

So, in my opinion, there is no such thing as magic or ability to interact with Jinn - These are false beliefs that have existed amongst humans since time immemorial and it's these beliefs that put humans very close to shirk if not right in it.

Answer (score -1):

First we need to differenciate magic and black magic.

Magic is about doing trick to make people believe that it is real. We can believe in magic because it is pure trick, if you train you can do that yourself.

Black magic is doing real things like cursing others to die, or make loss in their business, etc. like a witch.

You should never believe in black magic. Human are given certain ability, but not so much like killing a person 100 miles away by stabbing a needle into a doll or cursing. It is shirk, only Allah can make or destroy anything from nothing, if you believe a human can do it, you  are giving him the power of Allah. Anything that is physically (Physics law) impossible is black magic and believing in it is shirk.

And any working, possible black magic is actually a trick too. If you investigate it and research it well you will find it is a trick. I mean if it is actually a power how come anyone can study and utilize? and some are just belief and myths of people. It will totally oppose any logic and universal law.

Answer (score -2):

There should be no doubt or hesitance in affirming the teachings of Islam. This is definitely an issue which you urgently need to overcome, as true doubt is Kufr. -- But maybe you are ignorant on this topic and knowledge will quell these evil thoughts?

Strengthening your Islamic knowledge and logic/reason is the way to overcome this issue. -- Magic is real. It can affect people physically. Some of the most truthful people (including the Prophet (ﷺ)  himself) were afflicted by magic.. experiencing what they were not going through, among other things; they didn't just make these things up. And Ruqyah helped counter symptoms of magic.

Moreover, the Creator who made everything would know what is real or not. Magic is subject to His Will too. He said it is real and that those who engage in it (to hurt others, etc) are disbelievers. Magicians often utilize Jinn, whom we are forbidden to turn to.

Refer to people of knowledge/scholars to help you further. Or feel free to ask more questions here if you have them. May Allah (ﷻ) guide us all and keep us firm on Islam.

Comment: I'm doubtful that magic being real is a necessary belief. I'm not aware of it being explicitly mentioned that magic works in the Quran, or any mutawatir hadith. You could reject the ahadith talking about magic having effects in the world, and interpret the verses of the Quran that reference magic to mean "people believe and practice this, and that's the evil part; it doesn't actually work, like astrology". It seems to me that would be fisq, not kufr; perhaps this could be addressed in your answer.

Comment: I know that doubt is kufr but since I tried to get rid of these doubts doesn't that make me a believer?

Comment: @GBach - That approach to Islam isn't correct. It's not for people to reject hadith arbitrarily or to interpret the Qur'an as they see fit. Moreover, consider re-reading the Qur’an, because Allah (ﷻ) mentions real-world effects of magic which include separation of spouses (2:102), causing illusions such as the sticks that appeared to move like snakes to Moses (20:66), among others. God didn’t say they ‘intended’/’tried’/‘assumed' to do these things via magic, rather that these things actually happen/happened as a result of people using magic. And then of course, more evidence from the Sunnah.

Comment: @Mitun Khan - Assuming you had true doubts, trying to get rid of them is good (and the only way to overcome them) but it is not enough; if you then successfully reject/overcome all doubt and affirm that magic is real after you sought faith.. then of course you would be a Muslim.

Comment: I understand that throwing out some ahadith because their content seems nonsense is haram, but it's not kufr; and if you do throw out those ahadith relating to sihr, then that context falls away and what I mentioned could be one interpretation of the text. I'm not saying any of that is orthodox teaching or methodology, I'm just wondering whether it would be kufr or something less sinful. The point that there are specific supernatural effects of magic mentioned in the Quran is relevant though and seems somewhat conclusive.

Comment: @GBach - It could be one interpretation in the same way that throwing out scientific evidence which you dislike leads to new interpretations as well. Whether Haram/Kufr, you are still arriving to a false view by disregarding evidence from Islamic texts merely because you ‘dislike’ it.

Comment: @Insight01 I agree that it's not a sound methodology from an Islamic perspective, but that's not the question, the question I raised is "does not believing those ahadith constitute kufr", and I don't think it does. You may be arriving at an Islamically incorrect view, but that alone doesn't imply you're being a kafir. That's why I asked about other texts that unambiguously state or imply that magic exists and has real effects in the world. Rejecting anything in the Quran is clearly kufr; rejecting ahad ahadith is not.

Comment: Intellectually disbelieving in magic as a muslim doesn't make you kafir. The ayats in the quran about sihr are way away from being qat'i, rather they are all dhanni. For instance 2:102 which is talking about like gossips or tricks that make the woman and husband argue or whatever which might result to a divorce. See or read Othello and see how sihr i.e words was used. And mentioning the sihr in egypt in moses time it's clear that the quran states that the magicans "made sihr on their eyes of the people 7:116", as even street magicans can do today. Qurays used to call the prophet a sahir

Comment: ... they would say he is a sahir, he divide us with his words. Convince could be a synonym to sihr sometimes too.

Comment: "2:102 which is talking about like gossips" - Do you see mention of "gossips" anywhere in this verse or even context? :/ Please do not make things up. Gossip is talked about elsewhere in the Qur'an but it is not linked to disbelief. Magic on the other hand is linked to disbelief. AND, Qur'an mentions a method of magic ie blowing on knots. What "explanation" do you have for evil that occurs due to blowing on knots?

Comment: @Insight01 it doesn't have to be GOSSIP, that was just an example, but words, empty words, that deceives: see tafsir surat al mudatthir: verse "فَقَالَ إِنْ هَٰذَا إِلَّا سِحْرٌ يُؤْثَرُ"

أي يأثِره عن غيره. والسِّحر: الخديعة. وقد تقدم بيانه في سورة «البقرة». وقال قوم: السحر: إظهار الباطل في صورة الحق

Please don't tell people who doesn't agree with you to not make up things. It is true that the majority view is that sihr exist as in REAL magic, but there are some who doesn't interpret sihr in that sense. See for instance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6qoh4en4kI

Comment: @Muslimahياربالعالمين i dont thing verse 2:102 talks about REAL black magic.  "And [yet] they learn from them that by which they cause separation between a man and his wife. But they do not harm anyone through it except by permission of Allah". It clearly says it cannot harm anyone without the permission of Allah. It can only be considered a test from Allah himself. Jesus cured blind with the permission of Allah, it is not considered black magic but a miracle. Then how come a bad thing can be considered black magic but not a test from Allah?

Comment: @Muslimahياربالعالمين what evil was mentioned in verse 113:5, it also say about evil of enviers, it is the method they use to deal with the person they envy and not black magic. What about the Hadith which says about knot being untied when you wake up for fajr, doing wuduh and starting fajr prayer? It should refer to this knot which was done by Satan himself. The arabic word talks about female evil doers. There are also male evil doers, and many types of black magic not only knot types. Why doesn't this verse ask safety from other types of black magic. So this verse talks about fajr know only